# How to view foreign language(i.e. Bangla) characters in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to build an admin panel with Laravel framework for a website that is going to be in Bengali language. I can write Bangla fonts in my mysql database quite fine and when I insert directly into the database the fonts are displayed fine but when I try to insert Bangla from the panel and try to see the output through my laravel controllers, the fonts are not displayed. Can anyone give me a solution?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPtpb.png)

This is where I am trying to add a category name in Bangla. You can see the font working well here. I am using Avro Keyboard for inserting Bangla. But when I try to display it, it is displayed like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiHWx.png)
You can see that Bangla fonts are not working properly. Now this happens only when I am using laravel. I have inserted Bangla directly into mysql database in xampp but then it works fine.

```
$category->category_name = ucwords(strtolower($request->category_name));
```

This is the code I'm using in my controller to insert the category name.

I am using php 7 and database collation is utf8_general_ci. I am also using this meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my site's head section. Now could anyone please provide me a solution? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This could use a bit more detail - can you make a specific example of a string that you're entering, whether it ends up in the database, and what it looks like in your controllers (using what code, and what encoding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. In my controller I was using `strtolower()` and `ucwords()` when inserting the category name. That's what was causing the problem.

Comment: You need to use the mb_ functions possibly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php